# Using Android-NDK in Android Studio Build command fail

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android.mk

I am trying to add this project as Android-NDK to Android studio but I keep getting errors : https://github.com/timsu/android-aac-enc

I followed this guide to install `NDK` and everything related. Then I added the `jni folder` to the `app\src\main\jni` and added this line to `build.gradle`.

```
android {  
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path "src/main/jni/Android.mk"
        }
}
```

When I try to sync the project I get the following `error` :

```
Build command failed.

Error while executing process C:\Users\ThermalTake i7\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\ThermalTake i7\Desktop\StarMe Git\starme_android-code\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-19 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/ThermalTake i7/Desktop/StarMe Git/starme_android-code/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\ThermalTake i7\Desktop\StarMe Git\starme_android-code\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
'C:\Users\ThermalTake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

After searching for some answers I tried adding this line to the `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    defaultConfig
            {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a'
                }
            }
```

And still got the same error, what am I missing? 
Is adding the `jni` folder all that I have to do?

Also this is the `Android.mk` file, maybe the error is there.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/Config.mk

LOCAL_MODULE := aac-encoder

ENC_SRC := src

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/inc

LOCAL_SRC_FILES = \
    aac-enc.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/cmnMemory.c \
    basic_op/basicop2.c \
    basic_op/oper_32b.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/aac_rom.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/aacenc.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/aacenc_core.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/adj_thr.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/band_nrg.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/bit_cnt.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/bitbuffer.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/bitenc.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/block_switch.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/channel_map.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/dyn_bits.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/grp_data.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/interface.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/line_pe.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/memalign.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/ms_stereo.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/pre_echo_control.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/psy_configuration.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/psy_main.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/qc_main.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/quantize.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/sf_estim.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/spreading.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/stat_bits.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/tns.c \
    $(ENC_SRC)/transform.c

ifeq ($(VOTT), v5)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
    $(ENC_SRC)/asm/ARMV5E/AutoCorrelation_v5.s \
    $(ENC_SRC)/asm/ARMV5E/band_nrg_v5.s \
    $(ENC_SRC)/asm/ARMV5E/CalcWindowEnergy_v5.s \
    $(ENC_SRC)/asm/ARMV5E/PrePostMDCT_v5.s \
    $(ENC_SRC)/asm/ARMV5E/R4R8First_v5.s \
    $(ENC_SRC)/asm/ARMV5E/Radix4FFT_v5.s
endif

ifeq ($(VOTT), v7)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
    $(ENC_SRC)/asm/ARMV5E/AutoCorrelation_v5.s \
    $(ENC_SRC)/asm/ARMV5E/band_nrg_v5.s \
    $(ENC_SRC)/asm/ARMV5E/CalcWindowEnergy_v5.s \
    $(ENC_SRC)/asm/ARMV7/PrePostMDCT_v7.s \
    $(ENC_SRC)/asm/ARMV7/R4R8First_v7.s \
    $(ENC_SRC)/asm/ARMV7/Radix4FFT_v7.s
endif

LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := 
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES :=

LOCAL_CFLAGS := $(VO_CFLAGS)

ifeq ($(VOTT), v5)
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DARMV5E -DARM_INASM -DARMV5_INASM
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(ENC_SRC)/asm/ARMV5E
endif

ifeq ($(VOTT), v7)
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DARMV5E -DARMV7Neon -DARM_INASM -DARMV5_INASM -DARMV6_INASM
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(ENC_SRC)/asm/ARMV5E
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(ENC_SRC)/asm/ARMV7
endif

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Could it be because I have not included `NDK_MODULE_PATH`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NDK cannot be installed in a path that has spaces. Same for projects that use NDK.

In your case, the best fix would be to move all Android SDK to a directory C:\AndroidSdk.

Comment: That seemed to be the problem